# html 5 input type email $_post empty when submit

Tags: php, html, post

i have code like this,

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="email" class="form-control input-md" required="" />
```

and my action form php $email=$_POST["email"];
when i type echo $email, it not showing what i input.
but if i change

```
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="email" class="form-control input-md" required="" /> (type=text)
```

it show what i input , with type text, but not type = email , why? thanks

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing this in? IE9 doesn't support the type 'email' although I'm not sure that this would prevent the value from being posted.

Comment: If you have input type email try to write there any letters (not email) and if you don't get alert about wrong e-mail adress it means your browser doesn't support this type

Comment: Input type only validates whether you have entered the correct input or not. If you use type="email" in IE8 and enter an invalid email and press submit then also your input will be posted.

Comment: Assuming that the HTML your using is version 5, most likely your browser does not recognize the type="email", and not knowing what to do, does not make the correct assumption that it is regular text and therefore leaves the POST field blank.